# Can't return html from controller using Ajax calls in a Chat app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So i'm building an integrated chat app in CRM. Whenever the logged in user click on a contact it displays the chat history between both users using Ajax calls, and this is where troubles begin.

So here's my Ajax Call code:

```
function GetChatHistory(receiver_id){
    $.ajax({
              dataType : "json",
              url: '/chat/get_chat_history_by_user',
              data:{receiver_id:receiver_id},
              success:function(data)
              {

                  $('#chathistory').html(data);
                  ScrollDown();  
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                  // alert('Local error callback');
                  alert("error fetching")
              }
         });
}
```

this is my controller

```
public function get_chat_history_by_user(){
        //get the receiver id
        $receiver_id = $this->input->get('receiver_id');
        //get the sender id
        $Logged_sender_id = $this->session->userdata['user_id'];

        $history = $this->chat_model->GetReciverChatHistory($receiver_id);

        foreach($history as $chat):

            $message_id = $chat['id'];
            $sender_id = $chat['sender_id'];
            $userName = $this->UserModel->GetName($chat['sender_id']);
            $userPic = $this->UserModel->PictureUrlById($chat['sender_id']);

            $messagebody = $chat['message'];
            $messagedatetime = date('d M H:i A',strtotime($chat['message_date_time']));
      ?>
           <?php if($Logged_sender_id!=$sender_id){?>     
                  <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                    <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                      <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span ><?=$userName;?></span>
                        <span ><?=$messagedatetime;?></span>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->

                      <div class="direct-chat-text">
                         <?=$messageBody;?>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
            <?php }else{?>
               <!-- Message to the right -->
                    <div class="direct-chat-msg right">
                      <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                        <span ><?=$userName;?></span>
                        <span ><?=$messagedatetime;?></span>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->

                      <div class="direct-chat-text">
                        <?=$messageBody;?>
                       </div>
                       <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
             <?php }?>

       <?php
        endforeach;
 }
```

the simple version of the view and the div i want to insert data in it :

```
<div id="chathistory"></div>
```

Please note that the models are written correctly(i did test them), and the call is written correctly because whenever i remove the foreach loop and add this to my controller :

```
echo json_encode($history);
```

and then console log the data in my ajax call i get the full chat history without a problem. so my guess is that there's something wrong with foreach loop and the html rendering !

ALSO : i did review some simple web app chat on github and they did write the controller with the same manner and it work perfectly fine for them. So what do you think is the problem please?

Comment: Did you check your browser's Console for errors? Or do any other basic debugging steps? If the best you can say is "my guess is there's something wrong", then I suspect not. Debugging is almost as important a skill as the programming itself, please learn how to do the basics at least. Anyway, you almost certainly have a console error, because `dataType : "json"` tells jQuery to expect JSON in the response, but you are returning HTML from the controller. So it will likely throw an error when it tries to parse your HTML as JSON. Either remove that line, or specify `dataType: "html"` instead.

Comment: thank you for your feedback :). you're right it's important to learn debugging and i lack in this area i spend my time console logging things to figure out problems. and i will check the datatype property and let you know !

Comment: Thank you so much dude , that was the problem..... ! i changed it to html and everything worked !

Answer (score 1):

```
dataType : "json"
```

tells jQuery to expect JSON in the response, but you are returning HTML from the controller. So it will likely throw an error when it tries to parse your HTML as JSON. Either remove that line, or specify

```
dataType: "html"
```

instead